# MongoDB Ops Manager - CPU - No Data Available

Tags: mongodb

I have what I would consider a default installation of the latest version of MongoDB Ops Manager and MongoDB.

Everything is working except the Hardware > CPU monitor for my server.

Attached screenshots of the configuration and the screen showing no data.

[CPU not showing data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CqjoB.png)

[Server Info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9dGa.png)

Ops Manager Version - 3.4.6

Auth Schema - 5

Feature Compatability - 3.4

Advanced startup options (default) -

nojournal - false

logappend - true

syslog - false

slowms - 100

profile - 1

Log Path - /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: @joanolo - issue is CPU monitor is not showing data despite all best efforts.

Answer (score 1):

Ref:

https://docs.cloudmanager.mongodb.com/tutorial/configure-monitoring-munin-node/

To chart the hardware statistics collected with Munin, Cloud Manager supports the following munin-node plugins:

- cpu plugin, which creates the cputime chart.
- iostat plugin, which creates the iostat chart.
- iostat_ios plugin, which creates the iotime chart.

> You must install the munin-node package on all of the host systems
>   that you wish to monitor. Ensure that the Monitoring Agent can connect
>   to the munin-node process on port 4949 of the monitored host to
>   collect data.

Comment: thanks for pointing me at the main documentation.  However, as stated in the docs you point to:

"As of Automation Agent 2.7.0, hardware monitoring using munin-node is deprecated.

If you run munin-node on your MongoDB servers then install or upgrade to Automation Agent version 2.7.0 or later, Cloud Manager displays the hardware data that the Automation Agent collected, not what Munin had collected. The historical hardware data Munin collected is neither displayed nor saved."


I am using latest versions, so simply installing munin node doesnt fix the issue.